# php add "required" in imput field dynamic

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am searching for a solution but did not find a good example.

I have in form dropdown menu and input field. Now I want that input field to be required based on the selection from dropdown. I would like to have "required" dynamic based on selection.

here is my form:

```
<form name="coaching_save" method="POST" action="coaching_form.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

    <div class="item form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Issue">Issue <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <select name="Issue" id="Issue" required class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected hidden></option>
    <?php
    $tww_dd_sql = "SELECT * FROM `coaching_issue`";
    $tww_dd_result = $mysqli->query($tww_dd_sql);
    while($row = $tww_dd_result->fetch_array())
    {
    $row['id'];
    echo "<option value='".$row['issue']."'>".$row['issue']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
     </div>
    </div>


     <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Qfinity_ID_1">Qfinity ID <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">   
    <input type="text" required id="Qfinity_ID_1" name="Qfinity_ID_1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> 
    </div>
    </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">    
<button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

So in input field "Qfinity_ID_1" i would like to add "required" when "SbS" is selected from dropdown query (there are many other values to select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a bit of JavaScript here. If you're using jQuery, this would do it:

```
$(document).on('change','#Issue',function(){
  if($(this).val() === 'SbS') {
    $("#Qfinity_ID_1").prop('required',true);
  } else {
    $("#Qfinity_ID_1").prop('required',false);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4vqpkq7o/

Comment: I believe this answers your question, and although I believe it is already known to you: Be aware, that you should still check the client-sent data on server-side, because any malicious person can reset that field to non-required.

Comment: I try this but did not work, I think because in your demo you manually add dropdown but my dropdown is generated from SQL query

Comment: for some reason wont work even when i have fixed values, i see tah in jsfiddle is working but on my side wont. I put the JS in `<script>` tags in bottom of page, also have loaded jquery script in my page.

Comment: Make sure the jQuery is loaded before this script. Also, check if JavaScript is outputting any errors in the browser console (inside developer tools).

Comment: thank you, i did not consider that i need to load jQuery before script. Now it is working.